# Why does cat exit a shell script, but only when it's fed by a pipe?

Tags: shell, sed, sh, cat

Why does cat exit a shell script, but only when it's fed by a pipe?

Case in point, take this shell script called "foobar.sh":

```
#! /bin/sh
echo $#
echo $@
cat $1
sed -e 's|foo|bar|g' $1
```

And a text file called "foo.txt" which contains only one line:

```
foo
```

Now if I type `./foobar.sh foo.txt` on the command line, then I'll get this expected output:

```
1
foo.txt
foo
bar
```

However if I type `cat foo.txt | ./foobar.sh` then surprisingly I only get this output:

```
0

foo
```

I don't understand. If the number of arguments reported by `$#` is zero, then how can `cat $1` still return `foo`? And, that being the case, why doesn't `sed -e 's|foo|bar|g' $1` return anything since clearly $1 is `foo`?

This seems an awful lot like a bug, but I'm assuming it's magic instead. Please explain!

**UPDATE**

Based on the given answer, the following script gives the expected output, assuming a one-line foo.txt:

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ $# ]
then
yay=$(cat $1)
else
read yay
fi
echo $yay | cat
echo $yay | sed -e 's|foo|bar|g'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $1 is not "foo".   $1 is

ie, undefined/nothing.

Unlike a programming language, variables in the shell are quite dumbly and literally replaced, and the resulting commands textually executed (well, sorta kinda).  In this case, "cat $1"  becomes just "cat    ", which will take input from stdin.  That's terribly convenient to your execution since you've kindly provided "foo" on stdin via your pipe!

See what's happening?

sed likewise will read from stdin, but is already on end of stream, so exits.

Comment: OK but then how can I know what was sent over stdin? Is there an environment variable for that?

Comment: Nope.   There are some funny games you might play, but in general only the consumers of the stream get to see what is on the stream.   Think of it as a literal pipe.   You stuff some things in one end, they come out the other.   What happens inside is not transparent, you can't see in.

Comment: Well I could use the read command to assign stdin to a var and then go from there. I've updated my question...

Answer (score 2):

When you don't give an argument to `cat`, it reads from stdin. When `$1` isn't given the `cat $1` is the same as a simple `cat`, which reads the text you piped in (`cat foo.txt`).

Then the `sed` command runs, and same as `cat`, it reads from stdin because it has no filename argument. `cat` has already consumed all of stdin. There's nothing left to read, so `sed` quits without printing anything.